# MongoDb duplicate key erro

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting this error while trying to insert data in the MongoDB collection.

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: kaa.logs_96775772132708234336 index: id dup key: { _id: ObjectId('6001bdc2429b9313d755e106') }`

Here is my code :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var dbo = db.db("kaa");

        dbo.collection("logs_96775772132708234336").insertOne(document, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 document inserted");
            console.log(res.insertedId);
            db.close();
        });
    });
```

When I am searching for the same object id, I am getting data. It seems NodejS Mongo is creating a duplicate object ID.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are saying that the returns of  `collectionName.find({ _id: ObjectId("6001bdc2429b9313d755e106") })` is empty in database ?

Comment: No, actually I am getting 1 record. It seems NodeJs Mongo is creating duplicate ID when data insertion frequency is very high.

Comment: The ObjectIDs that the driver is generating are unique. The problem should be in your business logic. The current state of your "question" is simply a statement that you're trying to insert a document with the same ID and it doesn't work. If you need help for a specific problem, either edit this question completely(including the misleading title) and provide valid information or scrap it and create a new one which clearly explains what your problem is.

Comment: Here is my code which is giving the error.                                                                                           MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var dbo = db.db("kaa");

            dbo.collection("logs_96775772132708234336").insertOne(document, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document inserted");
                console.log(res.insertedId);
                db.close();
            });
        });

Comment: I am experiencing this same problem.  I have completely deleted the collection, and am reading documents from a text value.  The documents do not have an _id field in them.

Answer (score 1):

I do suspect that after insertOn your entity document is reciveng _id filed, which in result casues that you are insrting document with **that _id again**.

Check your document after inserting it

```
console.log(document._id);
```

As in mongo docs

> _id Field
>
> If the document does not specify an _id field, then mongod will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document
> before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id
> field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver
> or application does not.
>
> If the document contains an _id field, the _id value must be unique
> within the collection to avoid duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

I had  a error like that before and the solution was to delete the collection itself  and try again .